# In C++, can I define a pointer-to-member of a private class outside its scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider:

```
class C {
private:
   class T {int a, b;};
};

C::T *p;
```

As expected, this produces a compilation error saying that C::T is private in the context of Line 6.

Now change this to pointer-to-member:

```
class C {
private:
   class T {int a, b;};
};

int C::T::*p;
```

This time around, gcc version 3.2.3 still makes the same complaint, but gcc version 3.4.3 lets it pass.  Which is the correct behavior according to the standard?

Answer (score 3):

Since `T` *is* invisible from anywhere but the class `C` itself, I cannot imagine it would be allowed.

Tried this out on Comau, and he tells me the same.  Sadly enough I don't know my way around the standard enough, so can't point you there.

Answer (score 3):

To add to *xtofl*'s post, see chapter 11 ([class.access]) of the standard:

> A member of a class can be
>   — **private**; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is
>   declared.
>   — **protected**; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is
>   declared, and by members and friends of classes derived from this class (see 11.5).
>   — **public**; that is, its name can be used anywhere without access restriction.